# Using a variable in Awk command in script

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I am having a little trouble with using a variable and printing the 2nd field with the awk command.  I am attempting to grab a number from a value in a file. The value in the file looks like

MAX=10000  (I want the Number only), I am passing this into a variable in a script so in the script I have variables

```
parm_file=ParmFiles/Parmfile.parm
session=s_session_value

OLD_MAX_SEQ_NR=`awk -F '=' "/$session/ {getline; print $2}" < $parm_file`
```

because I have double quotes to identify the $session variable, it is taking the $2 as a variable too, and so it is just printing the whole line, instead of the second field.

I've tried also to pass the variable into the awk command like

```
OLD_MAX_SEQ_NR=`awk -F '=' \
    -v var="$session" \
    '/var/ {getline; print $2}' < $parm_file`
```

But it does not seem to be putting the variable where `var` is.  I have even tried hard coding the `-v var="s_session_value"` and it does not work.

I can't figure out a way to make the command look at the `$2` as it normally does instead of a variable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: awk is not shell, just like C is not shell. awk has variables and shell has variables but you can't directly access a shell variable in awk just like you can't access a shell variable in C. Post some sample input and expected output as you are like to get bad advice given what you have posted so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
parm_file=ParmFiles/Parmfile.parm
session=s_session_value

OLD_MAX_SEQ_NR=$(
    awk -F'=' -v pat="$session" \
        '$0 ~ pat {getline; print $2}' < "$parm_file"
)
```

- You need to pass shell variables to `awk` by defining an awk variable using `-v`.
- Using variable inside `/../` is taken as literal. So use `$0~var_name` construct.
- Using back-ticks is deprecated. Use command substitution `$(..)`
- Quote your variables.

Comment: Make sure you read all the pros and cons of [getline](http://awk.info/?tip/getline)!!!

Comment: the parm file would be something like this
[s_session_value]
$$MAX_SEQ=2345656

[s_session_value2]
$$MAX_SEQ=2345432

your solution worked great!  I was sure that I was trying to bring in the variable wrong when I used the -v.  Thank you for clarifying it.  Also the back-ticks was from other code that is used so I just followed what was used.  Can you explain why it is depreciated now?  Thanks for the solution though!

Comment: @Archer783 You're welcome. You can read [BashFAQ/82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky without a sample line of the parm file. But I don't understand why you don't use `cut`, it makes it much easier?

```
OLD_MAX_SEQ_NR=$(grep "$session" "$parm_file" | cut -d= -f2)
```